# get just the month, day or year part of NSDate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Say I have the following:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
```

How do I just the get integer value for the month? day? or year?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Or you could just use the NSDate class:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    int month = [[date descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"%m" timeZone:nil locale:nil] intValue];
    int day = [[date descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"%d" timeZone:nil locale:nil] intValue];
    int year = [[date descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"%Y" timeZone:nil locale:nil] intValue];

    NSLog(@"Today: %i-%i-%i", year, month, day);
```

Hope it works,
ief2

Comment: is it public API? I got warning for this.

Comment: It is probably deprecated by now

Answer (score 2):

You want this [NSDateCOmponenets](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

specifically:

```
- (NSDateComponents *)components:(NSUInteger)unitFlags  fromDate:(NSDate *)date
```

Comment: comps is never defined here?  I am just looking to split the current date into parts, seems so complex for such a simple thing